# Return record option as null when calling from C#

Tags: c#, f#, null, option-type, record

Is it ever possible to return `record option` value from F# to C# as null value? I want to encapsulate some logic in F# assembly, and hide as much as I can behind facade being "more natural to C#". Here's some synthetic example:

```
type Data = { DataField1: int; DataField2: string }
```

And code to return to C# would look like this:

```
type SomeFacade() =
    let data = Some { DataField1 = 1; DataField2 = "hello" }  

    member x.GetData() = if Option.isSome data then Option.get data else null
```

But it is not allowed to use null value.

- I could try to use `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` attribute, but it can't be used on record types.
- I could use `Class` instead of `Record` but it would be more complicated to work with it inside F# as most of work are supposed to be done inside the F# part. And I like the extremely convenient way of creating record values by copying another record value using `with` keyword.
- It is even possible to use `Data` as record inside F# assembly and convert it to some intermediate class `DataClass` when exposing to C# assemblies, but it looks awkward.

Is there any solution? (I'm not going to use null values inside F# code but I would like to return null values to C# code).

Comment: What's wrong with returning the option type?

Comment: Nothing... but I'm just playing with F# in a big solution containing only C# projects and I don't want types too specific to F# be seen outside F# assembly, let's name it "to hide implementation details". They can be seen but it would be better if they not. We don't use F# yet so I don't want my colleagues be scared too much with "unknown" programming language :)

Comment: Yes, sir. It worked for Mercurial adoption, so perhaps it will work with F# either :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For record types,

```
Operators.Unchecked.defaultof<Data>
```

is `null` (just tested using fsi)

This is probably the simplest solution